# Program Recognizes image/video depth

Tags: python-3.x

So I am looking to write a code that will be able to recognize depth within an image or video. I wanted to write this in python, but I come at a loss when brainstorming how to achieve this.In other words, I wanted my code to isolate a single moving object and save it's movement on a 3-D plane. I wanted to transfer the movement so I may be able to display it somewhere else. Are there any modules that are recommendable for this project or something that has worked in a similar project? Would something like REST be able to help?
All responses are appreciated.

Comment: I would think a math module, such as matplotlib or numpy might be useful. You can use an array, and track the position in that array with x, y, and z coordinates.